# how to organize or sort a std::vector <cv::Point2f>

Tags: c++

I have a vector full of cv::Point and I want to organize this vector so, that the Point with the smallest x and y value should be the first and the last one should have the highst x,y value ? any Idea how can I do that ?

Comment: What do you mean smallest x and y? Should (5, 10) go before or after (10, 5) for instance?

Comment: How do you define which of two (x,y) pairs is greater than the other? Once you have that, it is trivial using `std::sort` (there are plenty of SO posts on that).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use `std::sort`.

```
std::sort(vec.begin(), vec.end(), [](const cv::Point2f &a, const cv::Point2f &b) {
    return (/* This is where you would compare a and b however you want */);
});
```

Really, it's quite hard to tell what you deem as the greatest (x,y) pair and the least (x,y) pair. One solution is to add the coordinates to give them a magnitude.

I'd use the distance from the origin: `return a.x*a.x + a.y*a.y < b.x*b.x + b.y*b.y`

---

In case you can't use C++11 functionality, here's the equivalent of the above solution:

```
bool point_comparator(const cv::Point2f &a, const cv::Point2f &b) {
    return (/* Your expression */);
}

std::sort(vec.begin(), vec.end(), point_comparator);
```

Comment: Yeah, you're probably right. I guess we should wait for C++17 to kick in before we can assume C++ is an alias of C++11 /o/

Comment: @Magtheridon96 if my point has x any value how can I sort here ?  I tried std::sort(imageCorners.begin(),imageCorners.end()); 
it didn'T work

Comment: Because you're missing an argument (The function used to compare the points). Do you have access to C++11 functionality?

Comment: You can also pass a plain function.

Answer (score 2):

If your Point class has operator < that evaluates like your rule (or you can add one), just call `std::sort`.  Otherwise write your compare function and call  [std::sort](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/) second form passing it as last param.  You can make it a lambda if your compiler is C++11-compatible.

Remember that the compare function must be transitive.

Answer (score 2):

Let's just arbitrarily assume that you determine the value of a point by adding the x and y (big assumption). Sorting is a fairly simply process:

```
bool sort (const cv::Point p1, const cv::Point p2) { return (p1.x + p1.y) < (p2.x + p2.y)); }

//int main or where ever
//assuming name of vector is myVector
std::sort(myVector.begin(), myVector.end(), sort);
```

Just change the sort method to illustrate how you want to sort